# How to split a string in Oracle using substr/instr

Tags: sql, oracle

Good Morning Everyone,
I am trying to split a string from a column in an  oracle table into multiple columns based on finding a specific word in the string and then returning the value after the word.  The words in the criteria that I am looking for will always be the same, but may not always be in the same position.

The column name in my table is called Criteria
Here is an example of how the string looks that I am trying to split:

| criteria |
| --- |
| [SampleNum: '3230', SampleState: 'Ready', CollectionReason: 'Mandatory', Action: 'Submit'] |

So the task is to Parse Criteria into columns SampleNum,  SampleState,  Action, CollectionReason

I would like my results to look like the following:

| SampleNUm | SampleStatus | CollectionReason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3230 | Ready | Mandatory |

I have tried a few things like the following where I find the data between each comma, but that is just not helping as I am really trying to find a specific word, then retrieve the data after that word and before the comma.

Here is what I have come up with so far but again, not quite what I am looking for.
Any help will be appreciated to figure out how to find a particular word, then get the value after that word.
Thanks in advance

```sql
SELECT
   criteria,INSTR(criteria,',',1,1) AS first_comma,
   INSTR(criteria,',',1,2) AS second_comma,
   INSTR(criteria,',',1,3) AS third_comma
   ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,4) AS fourth_comma,
   INSTR(criteria,',',1,5) AS fifth_comma
   ,SUBSTR(criteria
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,1) + 1
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,2)
              - INSTR(criteria,',',1,1)
              - 1)
       AS column2
         ,SUBSTR(criteria
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,2) + 1
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,3)
              - INSTR(criteria,',',1,2)
              - 1)
       AS column3       
                ,SUBSTR(criteria
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,3) + 1
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,4)
              - INSTR(criteria,',',1,3)
              - 1)
       AS column4  
                       ,SUBSTR(criteria
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,4) + 1
             ,INSTR(criteria,',',1,5)
              - INSTR(criteria,',',1,4)
              - 1)
       AS column5       
              FROM
    table1
```

Comment: no, you need to look at using regular expressions and regexp_substr function

Comment: i would tra fson_table for that https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973

Comment: @nbk The OP does not have valid JSON as it uses the array brackets but has the object syntax in the middle except that the keys are unquoted and the values have single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(criteria, 'SampleNum:\s*''(.*?)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS SampleNum
  , REGEXP_SUBSTR(criteria, 'SampleState:\s*''(.*?)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS SampleState
  , REGEXP_SUBSTR(criteria, 'CollectionReason:\s*''(.*?)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS CollectionReason  
FROM 
  table1
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wIrlogkK)

Comment: Thank you Trung.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I tried it out on my end and I get the results as they should look and requested.  I am very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the position of the quotes and then use that to find the sub-strings:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(criteria, q1 + 1, q2 - q1 - 1) AS samplenum,
       SUBSTR(criteria, q3 + 1, q4 - q3 - 1) AS samplestate,
       SUBSTR(criteria, q5 + 1, q6 - q5 - 1) AS collectionreason
FROM   (
  SELECT criteria,
         INSTR(criteria, '''', 1, 1) AS q1,
         INSTR(criteria, '''', 1, 2) AS q2,
         INSTR(criteria, '''', 1, 3) AS q3,
         INSTR(criteria, '''', 1, 4) AS q4,
         INSTR(criteria, '''', 1, 5) AS q5,
         INSTR(criteria, '''', 1, 6) AS q6
  FROM   table1
);
```

Regular expressions are slower than simple string functions; in this case, they make it immediately obvious where you are getting the data from and the expected format so might it be worth it from a development/maintenance point-of-view:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         criteria,
         '^\[SampleNum: ''(.*?)'', SampleState: ''(.*?)'', CollectionReason: ''(.*?)'', Action: ''(.*?)''\]$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS samplenum,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         criteria,
         '^\[SampleNum: ''(.*?)'', SampleState: ''(.*?)'', CollectionReason: ''(.*?)'', Action: ''(.*?)''\]$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS samplestate,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         criteria,
         '^\[SampleNum: ''(.*?)'', SampleState: ''(.*?)'', CollectionReason: ''(.*?)'', Action: ''(.*?)''\]$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         3
       ) AS collectionreason
FROM   table1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (criteria) AS
SELECT '[SampleNum: ''3230'', SampleState: ''Ready'', CollectionReason: ''Mandatory'', Action: ''Submit'']' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| SAMPLENUM | SAMPLESTATE | COLLECTIONREASON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3230 | Ready | Mandatory |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yBSj2UVC)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I used the solution that came in first but yours seems to be the same also.  Thank you very much.